# Set maximum form field length in React Admin

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-admin

Is there some way to set a field in a [SimpleForm](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/doc/4.0/SimpleForm.html) within [React-Admin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-admin) to limit the number of characters a user can type into that field?

Based on the [docs](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Tutorial.html), the React-Admin framework itself does not appear to contain this functionality. There is [validation](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Validation.html) functionality to show an error when the user types too many characters, but apparently no built-in way to limit the number of characters typed. Given this, has anyone achieved this via other means?

For example, say the valid values for a 'Status' field are only 'A', 'B' or 'C'. How, while using React-Admin, would you limit that form field to accept only 1 character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not strictly related to react-admin, but here you go:

```js
// react-admin / MUI
<NumberInput inputProps={{ maxLength: 1 }} source="my_source" />

//HTML
<input type="number" maxLength=1 />
```